# Django TextChoices Behavior

Tags: django

```
class MyTypes(TextChoices):
    MINE_AAA = '1', 'a',
    MINE_BBB = '2', 'b',
    MINE_CCC = '3', 'c',
    MINE_DDD = '4', 'd',
    MINE_EEE = '5', 'e'

    my_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MyTypes.choices)
```

I have been struggling a lot with being able to use Choices in my models. With the above example, if I create an instance "my_obj" and set "my_obj.my_type" to "MyTypes.MINE_BBB", the if I look at the "my_obj", its type is MyTypes. However, if I later query "my_obj" and look at "my_obj.my_type", its type is now a string.

So, when I create the object initially and serialize it, the serializer needs to handle MyTypes, but if I serialize the value after a query, the serializer needs to handle a string.

What I was really expecting when using a TextChoices field was that the value stored in the Database would be the single character, but when I reference it in code, I would see my MyTypes.

Are we not supposed to get the TextChoices instance back when we reference the model? If not, what is the simplest way to get it? It seem that if I after iterate through the MyTypes.choices to get it, that it really doesn't provide much value.

Here is what the documentation looks like.

```
class YearInSchool(models.TextChoices):
        FRESHMAN = 'FR', _('Freshman')
        SOPHOMORE = 'SO', _('Sophomore')
        JUNIOR = 'JR', _('Junior')
        SENIOR = 'SR', _('Senior')
        GRADUATE = 'GR', _('Graduate')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the `MyTypes` instance like so:

```py
MyTypes('1') == MyTypes.MINE_AAA
```

So in your code, whenever you want the type of `my_obj`, as a MyTypes instance you can do `MyType(my_obj.my_type)`.

I recommend writing a method for it:

```py
class MyModel(models.model):
    class MyType(TextChoices):
        ...

    my_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MyTypes.choices)

    def get_type(self):
        return MyModel.MyType(self.my_type)
```

Comment: `MyTypes(label)` is not a thing. It should be `MyTypes(value)` or `MyTypes(attr)`, e.g. `MyTypes('1') == MyTypes['MINE_AAA'] = MyTypes.MINE_AAA`

Comment: For ease of memory, `MyType(my_type_value)` is a bit analog to `int(some_str)` or `tuple(x)`. Seems I still managed to mistype `MyType[attr]` in my original comment though.

Answer (score 0):

the choices field need to be a list of tuple

```
class MyTypes(TextChoices):
    MINE_AAA = ('1', 'a',)
    MINE_BBB = ('2', 'b',)
    MINE_CCC = ('3', 'c',)
    MINE_DDD = ('4', 'd',)
    MINE_EEE = ('5', 'e')

    MY_CHOICES = [
        MINE_AAA,
        MINE_BBB,
        MINE_CCC,
        MINE_DDD,
        MINE_EEE
    ]

    my_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MY_CHOICES)
```

Here is what the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) looks like.

```
class YearInSchool(models.TextChoices):
        FRESHMAN = 'FR', _('Freshman')
        SOPHOMORE = 'SO', _('Sophomore')
        JUNIOR = 'JR', _('Junior')
        SENIOR = 'SR', _('Senior')
        GRADUATE = 'GR', _('Graduate')
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to help and the documentation doesn't include the ()s. I did notice that I had commas on each line, so I removed those, but it still doesn't work. Adding documentation sample to my post.

Comment: from the doc "iterables of exactly two items (e.g. [(A, B), (A, B) ...]) to use as choices",

the choices field is a list/tuple of list/tuple , the  fisrt is the value stored , the seconde the display value.

if the choice are MINE_BBB , the sotred value ( value en data base ) is '2', the display value (to print my_obj.get_my_type_display() ) is 'b', the doc explaine very well , https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/

Comment: No need to define `MY_CHOICES`, use `MyTypes.choices`. `a = 1, 2` is equivalent to `a = (1, 2)`. Like OP, fields belong on a `models.Model`.

Answer (score 0):

TextChoice for Gender Selection, first of all you have to import

> from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

```
class Gender(models.TextChoices):
    MALE = "male", _("Male")
    FEMALE = "female", _("Female")
    OTHER = "other", _("Other")
```